# Can I know char-array-size to which a char pointer variable points?

Tags: c

I must know array size to which a char pointer variable points.

But you know sizeof operation is not working.

```
char a[5];
char *b= a;
int c = sizeof(b);
printf("%d", sizeof(b)); // 8(64 bit cpu) printed, not 5 .
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's impossible. You're welcome.

Comment: Store it somewhere when allocating, and then look it up when needed.

Comment: Also, "%d" is not the right format specifier for `size_t`.

Comment: you are printing the size of a pointer (to a char in this case).

Comment: @Oren `strlen` is a horrible suggestion for this.

Comment: sizeof(b) is pointer size, array a size: sizeof(a)/sizeof(char) == 5

Comment: @cnicutar thanks, removed it.

Comment: Have you considered *storing it*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, once you convert it to a pointer (which is also done when passing the array as an argument to a function) you loose all size information about the array.

Comment: It seems that there is only one way to do this...

Answer (score 1):

If some piece of code needs to know the size of an array, make sure the code that calls it *tells* it the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers (which is what arrays decay to when you do things like these) don't "know" anything about the size of the data they're pointing at. You need to track it separately.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you say since I use english as a second language. your writing is so elegant...

Answer (score 0):

you cannot get that information, the only thing you could do is to embeddd the information if it is something you need:

```
int* array = malloc( sizeof(int) * (n + 1) );
*array = n;
++array;
```

then when you want to know the size

```
int n = *(array - 1);
```

same can be done with char or whatever type you need.

Answer (score -1):

This may be because of of 4 byte alignment.

To confirm try a[8], a[10] etc

Comment: No it's not. It's because `sizeof` yields the size of the object, i.e. the size of the pointer just like it yields the size of the array when an array is the operand.